# Why Dispose is not called in case of using block and object initializer

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, dispose, ilspy

Why Dispose() is not called in case of using and object initializer ?
I have the following code:

```
public sealed class MyDisposeClass : IDisposable
{
    private int _value;

    public MyDisposeClass(string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"MyDisposeClass: {str}");
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set => _value = value / 0;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose");
    }
}

public static class MyProgram
{
    public static void Go()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BEFORE USING");
        using (new MyDisposeClass("message") { Value = 100 })
        {
            Console.WriteLine("INSIDE USING");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("AFTER USING");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MyProgram.Go();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

And IlSpy shows me this:

```
public static void Go()
{
    Console.WriteLine("BEFORE USING");
    using (new MyDisposeClass("message")
    {
        Value = 100
    })
    {
        Console.WriteLine("INSIDE USING");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("AFTER USING");
}
```

And ILCode:

```
// [29 9 - 29 10]
IL_0000: nop

// [30 13 - 30 47]
IL_0001: ldstr        "BEFORE USING"
IL_0006: call         void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_000b: nop

// [31 13 - 31 66]
IL_000c: ldstr        "message"
IL_0011: newobj       instance void ClassLibrary1.MyDisposeClass::.ctor(string)
IL_0016: dup
IL_0017: ldc.i4.s     100 // 0x64
IL_0019: callvirt     instance void ClassLibrary1.MyDisposeClass::set_Value(int32)
IL_001e: nop
IL_001f: stloc.0      // V_0
.try
{

  // [32 13 - 32 14]
  IL_0020: nop

  // [33 17 - 33 51]
  IL_0021: ldstr        "INSIDE USING"
  IL_0026: call         void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_002b: nop

  // [34 13 - 34 14]
  IL_002c: nop
  IL_002d: leave.s      IL_003a
} // end of .try
finally
{

  IL_002f: ldloc.0      // V_0
  IL_0030: brfalse.s    IL_0039
  IL_0032: ldloc.0      // V_0
  IL_0033: callvirt     instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
  IL_0038: nop

  IL_0039: endfinally
} // end of finally

// [35 13 - 35 46]
IL_003a: ldstr        "AFTER USING"
IL_003f: call         void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_0044: nop
```

Comment: The construction happens before you enter the `using` statement. If the constuction fails (as it does in your case), then you never enter the `using` statement, and your type never gets disposed.

Comment: @canton7 but is it created ? we need to dispose smth only if it is created, right.

Comment: There's an [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2930) for this, courtesy of yours truly (although that specifically deals with `using`-declarations, not blocks, as there the issue is even more prominent).

Comment: As far as the `using` statement is concerned, it isn't created until the object initializer has finished running. If you need to dispose it if the object initializer fails, you need to write `using (var myClass = new MyDisposeClass(...)) { myClass.Value = 100; ... }`

Comment: Technically, it's not the construction that fails. You are using an object initializer and as you can see in the ILSpy output, that is called immediately after construction, but before entering the using block. It is inside of the parenthesis of the using clause. If you move the initialisation (Value = 100) inside the using block, Dispose() will be called.